# nginx force serve local file, instead of web URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to authenticate user, then serve the requested file.

URL: `http://example.com/stream/asd.m3u8`
Static file: `/stream/asd.m3u8` (/ = Linux filesystem's root)

```
location ~ /stream/(.*)\.m3u8 {
   # authentication happens here, but commented out
     for debugging, and had the results below;


   alias /stream/;
   # 403 Forbidden (the directory and contents has chmod 777)

   rewrite /stream/(.*)\.m3u8 /stream/$1;
   # Infinite loop (curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed)

   rewrite /stream/(.*)\.m3u8 /stream/$1 break;
   # 404 Not Found (in web root, that file doesn't exist)

   try_files /stream/$1.m3u8 =404;
   # 404 Not Found

   try_files /stream/$1.m3u8 =505;
   # 505
}
```

I think nginx treats `/stream/asd.m3u8` as a web URL.
How can I force it to treat `/stream/asd.m3u8` as a local file?

Also, what could cause the 403 on alias directive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI is the same as the pathname, which means that the document root is `/`. The document root is set using the `root` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

To set the correct document root for any URI that begins with `/stream/` use:

```
location /stream/ {
    root /;
}
```

---

If you have other files in this location, and only want to serve those ending with `.m3u8`, you could use your existing regular expression `location` block:

```
location ~ ^/stream/.*\.m3u8 {
    root /;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

---

The `alias` directive is not necessary here, in which case the `root` directive is preferred. To use `alias` inside a regular expression, you must capture the entire URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I thought it would create a vulnerability, but then I remembered it works only in /stream/

Comment: Indeed, that `root` needs to be protected by a location. Note also. that the regular expression is missing a leading `^`. I have added it in my answer.